# Total Probability theorem and Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Two reinforced concrete buildings A and B are located in a seismic region. It is estimated that an impending earthquake in the region might be strong (S), moderate (M), or weak (W) with probabilities.

P (S) = 0.02, P (M) = 0.2, and P (W) = 0.78.

The probabilities of failure of each building if these earthquakes occur are 0.20, 0.05, and 0.01, respectively.Due to similar procedures used in the design and construction of the two buildings, it is estimated that if building A fails the probability that building B will also fail is 0.50, 0.15, and 0.02 for the three types of earthquakes. If building A has failed and building B has survived, what is the probability that the earthquake was not strong?

$$P( \bar{S}|(A\cap\bar{B}))=\frac{P((A\cap\bar{B})|\bar{S})P(\bar{S})}{P(A \cap\bar{B})}$$
I am able to calculate $$ P(A \cap\bar{B}) and P(\bar{S})$$ but am suck on $$P((A\cap\bar{B})|\bar{S})$$
Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

$P(AF/S) = P(BF/S) = 0.2\times 0.02 = 0.004$

$P(AF/M) = P(BF/M) = 0.05\times 0.2 = 0.01$

$P(AF/W) = P(BF/W) = 0.01\times 0.78 = .0078$

$P(AS/S) = P(BS/S) = 0.8\times 0.02 = .016$

$P(AS/M) = P(BS/M) = 0.95\times 0.2 = 0.19$

$P(AS/W) = P(BS/W) = 0.99\times 0.78 = 0.7722$

These are independent probabilities of failure of A and B.

$P(BFS/AFS) = 0.5$

$P(BFM/AFM) = 0.15$

$P(BFW/AFW) = 0.02$

This is what is given,

$P(BF) = P(BFS/AFS)*P(AFS)+P(BFM/AFM)*P(AFM)+P(BFW/AFW)*P(AFW)$

$=0.5\times 0.004+.15\times 0.01+0.02\times 0.0078$

$=0.003656$
$P(BF/AF) = P(BSS/AFS)*P(AFS)+P(BSM/AFM)*P(AFM)+P(BSW/AFW)*P(AFW)$

$P(BS/AF) = 0.5\times 0.004+0.85\times 0.01+0.98\times 0.0078=0.002+0.0085+0.007644=0.018144$

Now use Bayes' theorem:

$P(\bar S/(BS/AF)) = \dfrac{(P(BSM/AFM)*P(AFM)+P(BSW/AFW)*P(AFW))}{P(BS/AF)} =\frac{(0.0085+0.007644)}{0.018144} = \frac{0.016144}{0.018144}=0.88977$

Comment: Hi satish, I could also do the part you wrote i.e. calculating P(A,B') but I got stuck at the part about how to calculate the conditional probability of the same given earthquake is not strong.

Comment: see the edit, I think it is correct.

Comment: @Did, I gave a solution and was wondering if you could let me know if it is correct.  I  have never worked on three series of events and I was confused on the partitioning part.  Will you help me vet the solution.  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @Did, the notations are A, B for buildings, S, F are for Survival and Failure, and S,M,W is for strong, moderate and weak earthquakes.  Thanks!!